# Can I perform inverse trig functions in Spotlight?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Is there a way to make Spotlight return the sin<sup>-1</sup>, cos<sup>-1</sup>, or tan<sup>-1</sup> of a given number without opening Calculator.app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

asin(x), acos(x), and atan(x) work for me. Spotlight gives the results in radians and will not show any calculator results if you go out of the domains for these functions.

Edit: If you want the results in degrees instead of radians, use asind(x), acosd(x), and atand(x).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there's a way to display degrees instead of radians?

Comment: @TheKraken You add "d" to the end to get degrees. For example, acosd(). I didn't know that before but stumbled upon it here: http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/1nhdjb/